# Not able set up zend framework in netbeans

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans

I am struggling to start developing zend framework application in netbeans since last few days I followed everything mentioned in video,tutorial found on zend web site.
Problem with me is that I am not able to register provider in netbeans.
I have set include path to `C:xampp/php/PEAR` and also have set PHP interpreter to `C:\xampp\php\php.exe`.
But I don't understand what is problem with it.

I am getting this error:

```
nb-commnands not found
```

Comment: Have you unzipped Zend Framework under C:xampp/php/PEAR/Zend/

Comment: under the __options php Zend__ tab in net beans is the __Zend Script__ path correct? Does it point to the `/bin/zf.bat` file that your installation of Zend Framework uses. Xampp comes bundled with a version of ZF (at least it did when I used it) so you have to make sure you are pointing to the correct __zf.bat__.

Comment: ok it's working now but still i am not running my project. whenever i run project it shows indexes

Comment: @user1511547, which version of ZF are you using? I am using ZF2 and I am not able to setup NetBeans for ZF2. Any ideas!

Comment: @Raaks read rocly's comments it solved my problem but i am still not able to run my project

Comment: @user1511547, I followed Rocky's comments but my problem is that Im using ZendFramework2 and right now it does not have any zf.bat file in bin folder. Any information would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Windows Environment Variable PATH [like this](http://www.kilinjal.com/blog/how-configure-zend-tool-netbeans?page=show)

Answer (score 0):

NetBeansCommandsProvider.php is available in the netbeans installation folder, example "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.9\php\zend", copy the file in to the php include_path, example C:\ZendFramework-1.10.5\library or add "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.9\php\zend" to the include_path.